# What should my ini file for Eclipse look like?

Tags: eclipse, ini, eclipse-kepler

Kepler's ini file (config.ini) looks like this:

```
 org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
 eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.standard
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Documents/workspace
 osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242.jar
 equinox.use.ds=true
 eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
 osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.400.v20130327-    
2119.jar@1\:start
 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigura
tor/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
```

Is this how it is supposed to look? B/c it looks awfully different from others.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct `config.ini`.

You might be thinking of the `eclipse.ini` which does look very different.